# Problems with controlling SVG colors from outside through CSS

Tags: html, css, svg

I got an SVG from a designer of which I'd like to set the color through CSS from outside of the SVG. I managed to overwrite part of the colors, but not all. What would I need to do to have the icon unfilled, with red lines over the grey background? Ideally without modifying the SVG because there are plenty of them with similar structure.

```css
html {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
}

.icon{
  height: 6rem;
  width: 6rem;
}

svg {
  fill:red;
}
```

```html
<html>
<div class="icon">
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 24.1.3, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" baseProfile="basic" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px"
   y="0px" viewBox="0 0 76.5 76.5" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
  .st0{display:none;}
  .st1{fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:2;}
  .st2{fill:#FFFFFF;}
  .st3{fill:none;stroke:#FFFFFF;stroke-width:5;}
  .st4{fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:2;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;}
  .st5{display:inline;}
  .st6{font-family:'Akkurat-Bold';}
  .st7{font-size:7.0024px;}
  .st8{display:inline;fill:#2B3427;}
  .st9{fill:none;stroke:#2B3427;stroke-width:2;}
  .st10{fill:none;stroke:#2B3427;stroke-width:2;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;}
  .st11{display:inline;fill:#FFFFFF;}
  .st12{fill:#2B3427;}
</style>
<g id="Vorlagen" class="st0">
</g>
<g id="Kreis_Black">
  <path d="M38.3,4.8c18.4,0,33.4,15,33.4,33.4s-15,33.4-33.4,33.4S4.8,56.7,4.8,38.3S19.8,4.8,38.3,4.8 M38.3,2.8
    C18.7,2.8,2.8,18.7,2.8,38.3s15.9,35.4,35.4,35.4s35.4-15.9,35.4-35.4S57.8,2.8,38.3,2.8L38.3,2.8z"/>
  <path d="M38.3,4.8c18.4,0,33.4,15,33.4,33.4s-15,33.4-33.4,33.4S4.8,56.7,4.8,38.3S19.8,4.8,38.3,4.8 M38.3,2.8
    C18.7,2.8,2.8,18.7,2.8,38.3s15.9,35.4,35.4,35.4s35.4-15.9,35.4-35.4S57.8,2.8,38.3,2.8L38.3,2.8z"/>
</g>
<g id="Illu">
  <g>
    <path class="st1" d="M35.2,43.3c-1.5,1-9.1,3.6-14.7-1.1c-4-3.3-4.4-8.7-3.6-24.9c9.5-0.9,17.4,0.9,22,5c4.1,3.6,3.9,8.6,4.3,11.2
      C43.6,36.5,39.5,40.4,35.2,43.3z"/>
    <path class="st2" d="M44.8,41.6c9.7,6,18.3-7.2,20.2-15.9c-5.5-3.6-13-2.3-17.7,0.6C43.8,28.5,39.2,35,44.8,41.6"/>
    <path class="st3" d="M44.8,41.6c9.7,6,18.3-7.2,20.2-15.9c-5.5-3.6-13-2.3-17.7,0.6C43.8,28.5,39.2,35,44.8,41.6z"/>
    <path class="st2" d="M44.8,41.6C57.2,51.9,63,36.7,64.9,25.7c-8.2-3.9-13-2.3-17.7,0.6C43.8,28.5,39.2,35,44.8,41.6"/>
    <path class="st1" d="M44.8,41.6C57.2,51.9,63,36.7,64.9,25.7c-8.2-3.9-13-2.3-17.7,0.6C43.8,28.5,39.2,35,44.8,41.6z"/>
    <path class="st4" d="M22.7,22.6c0,0,14.8,6,11.3,43.2c0,0,12.4-31.6,24-36.1"/>
  </g>
  <rect x="21.1" y="47.3" class="st2" width="32.6" height="8.1"/>
</g>
<g id="Typo" class="st0">
  <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 25.4238 53.8332)" class="st5 st6 st7">VEGAN</text>
</g>
<g id="Typo_Gepfadet">
  <g>
    <path d="M28.1,53.8h-1l-1.6-5h1l1.2,3.8l1.2-3.8h0.9L28.1,53.8z"/>
    <path d="M30.8,53.8v-5h3.5v0.8h-2.6v1.2H34v0.8h-2.3V53h2.6v0.8H30.8z"/>
    <path d="M38.9,53.8l-0.1-0.5c-0.1,0.3-0.6,0.6-1.2,0.6c-0.6,0-1.1-0.1-1.5-0.6c-0.5-0.5-0.6-1.2-0.6-2s0.1-1.5,0.6-2
      c0.4-0.4,0.9-0.6,1.5-0.6c0.6,0,1.1,0.2,1.5,0.6c0.2,0.3,0.4,0.6,0.5,1h-0.9c0-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.2-0.5c-0.2-0.2-0.4-0.3-0.8-0.3
      c-0.3,0-0.6,0.1-0.8,0.3c-0.3,0.4-0.4,1-0.4,1.4s0,1.1,0.4,1.5c0.2,0.2,0.5,0.3,0.8,0.3c0.3,0,0.6-0.1,0.7-0.3
      c0.3-0.3,0.3-0.6,0.3-1h-1.2v-0.8h2.1v2.7H38.9z"/>
    <path d="M44,53.8l-0.3-1h-2l-0.3,1h-0.9l1.7-5h1l1.7,5H44z M42.7,50L42,52.1h1.4L42.7,50z"/>
    <path d="M49.1,53.8l-2.2-3.4v3.4H46v-5h1l2.1,3.4v-3.4H50v5H49.1z"/>
  </g>
</g>
<g id="Ikons_x5F_Grün" class="st0">
  <path class="st8" d="M38.3,4.8c18.4,0,33.4,15,33.4,33.4s-15,33.4-33.4,33.4S4.8,56.7,4.8,38.3S19.8,4.8,38.3,4.8 M38.3,2.8
    C18.7,2.8,2.8,18.7,2.8,38.3s15.9,35.4,35.4,35.4s35.4-15.9,35.4-35.4S57.8,2.8,38.3,2.8L38.3,2.8z"/>
  <path class="st8" d="M38.3,4.8c18.4,0,33.4,15,33.4,33.4s-15,33.4-33.4,33.4S4.8,56.7,4.8,38.3S19.8,4.8,38.3,4.8 M38.3,2.8
    C18.7,2.8,2.8,18.7,2.8,38.3s15.9,35.4,35.4,35.4s35.4-15.9,35.4-35.4S57.8,2.8,38.3,2.8L38.3,2.8z"/>
  <g class="st5">
    <path class="st9" d="M35.2,43.3c-1.5,1-9.1,3.6-14.7-1.1c-4-3.3-4.4-8.7-3.6-24.9c9.5-0.9,17.4,0.9,22,5c4.1,3.6,3.9,8.6,4.3,11.2
      C43.6,36.5,39.5,40.4,35.2,43.3z"/>
    <path class="st2" d="M44.8,41.6c9.7,6,18.3-7.2,20.2-15.9c-5.5-3.6-13-2.3-17.7,0.6C43.8,28.5,39.2,35,44.8,41.6"/>
    <path class="st3" d="M44.8,41.6c9.7,6,18.3-7.2,20.2-15.9c-5.5-3.6-13-2.3-17.7,0.6C43.8,28.5,39.2,35,44.8,41.6z"/>
    <path class="st2" d="M44.8,41.6C57.2,51.9,63,36.7,64.9,25.7c-8.2-3.9-13-2.3-17.7,0.6C43.8,28.5,39.2,35,44.8,41.6"/>
    <path class="st9" d="M44.8,41.6C57.2,51.9,63,36.7,64.9,25.7c-8.2-3.9-13-2.3-17.7,0.6C43.8,28.5,39.2,35,44.8,41.6z"/>
    <path class="st10" d="M22.7,22.6c0,0,14.8,6,11.3,43.2c0,0,12.4-31.6,24-36.1"/>
  </g>
  <rect x="21.1" y="47.3" class="st11" width="32.6" height="8.1"/>
  <g class="st5">
    <path class="st12" d="M28.1,53.8h-1l-1.6-5h1l1.2,3.8l1.2-3.8h0.9L28.1,53.8z"/>
    <path class="st12" d="M30.8,53.8v-5h3.5v0.8h-2.6v1.2H34v0.8h-2.3V53h2.6v0.8H30.8z"/>
    <path class="st12" d="M38.9,53.8l-0.1-0.5c-0.1,0.3-0.6,0.6-1.2,0.6c-0.6,0-1.1-0.1-1.5-0.6c-0.5-0.5-0.6-1.2-0.6-2s0.1-1.5,0.6-2
      c0.4-0.4,0.9-0.6,1.5-0.6c0.6,0,1.1,0.2,1.5,0.6c0.2,0.3,0.4,0.6,0.5,1h-0.9c0-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.2-0.5c-0.2-0.2-0.4-0.3-0.8-0.3
      c-0.3,0-0.6,0.1-0.8,0.3c-0.3,0.4-0.4,1-0.4,1.4s0,1.1,0.4,1.5c0.2,0.2,0.5,0.3,0.8,0.3c0.3,0,0.6-0.1,0.7-0.3
      c0.3-0.3,0.3-0.6,0.3-1h-1.2v-0.8h2.1v2.7H38.9z"/>
    <path class="st12" d="M44,53.8l-0.3-1h-2l-0.3,1h-0.9l1.7-5h1l1.7,5H44z M42.7,50L42,52.1h1.4L42.7,50z"/>
    <path class="st12" d="M49.1,53.8l-2.2-3.4v3.4H46v-5h1l2.1,3.4v-3.4H50v5H49.1z"/>
  </g>
</g>
</svg>

</div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why not simply remove the style part inside the SVG ?
(and create your own css *[in the html HEAD]* with the colors you want)

other just use css `!impotant` in your css

```
html { background-color: #eeeeee; }
.icon{
  height: 6rem;
  width: 6rem;
  }
svg { fill:red; }

/* add: */
.st1 { stroke:blue   !important; }
path { stroke:orange !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

SVG is a regular HTML element. Therefore it takes background-color: white or transparent instead of fill to stylize its background.